# Не могу установить pyicu

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

При запуске кода появилась ошибка "No icu module".
Я начал устанавливать pyicu. В `cmd` прописал:

```
pip install icu
```

Вот здесь обсуждается похожая проблема: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940188/error-installing-pip-pyicu

Но я не разобрался с порядком действий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите [готовый Python wheel отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu).

Пример для Python 3.6 (64-bit):

```
(ml) D:\download>pip install "PyICU-2.0.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
Processing d:\download\pyicu-2.0.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: PyICU
Successfully installed PyICU-2.0.3
```

Comment: При попытке установить появилась вот такая ошибка: Requirement 'PyICU-2.0.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov, вам не понятен смысл ошибки?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, "файл не существует". Но это, насколько, я понимаю, не так

Comment: укажите полный путь к файлу или перейдите в директорию, в которую вы скачали данный `.whl` файл...

Comment: При дальнейших попытках стала появляться ошибка: PyICU-2.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Какая у вас версия Python и платформа (32-bit, 64-bit)?

Comment: python: 3.6.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: windows 64bit..

Comment: `PyICU-2.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` - это `WHL` для Python 3.7.x. Скачайте правильную версию...

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu больше не работает