# Обработка дат разных локализаций в Pandas. PyICU или "ручками"?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, datetime, timezone

При работе с интернет магазином приходится обрабатывать данные разных локализаций. В них присутствует дата, которая важна для обработки. Естественно, формат даты разный в смысле разных языков - испанский, французский, английский, немецкий т др.

Вот например для испанского:
"9 sept 2021 12:19:03 GMT-7"
"8 feb 2022 23:28:33 GMT-8"
"1 ago 2021 00:31:47 GMT-7"

Когда пытаешься использовать в Pfndas pd.to_datetime() то получаешь ошибки.

```
pd.to_datetime("1 ago 2021 00:31:47 GMT-7")
    
ParserError: Unknown string format: 1 ago 2021 00:31:47 GMT-7
```

По теме есть решения [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927654/using-dateutil-parser-to-parse-a-date-in-another-language) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814855/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-pyicu/814868#814868)  - использовать модуль `PyICU`.   Но для него нет "родной" инсталляции для Windows.
В то же время меня подмывает "ручками" заменить для каждого языка нужные сокращения для месяцев и использовать `pd.to_datetime()` после контекстной замены.  А то для каждого языка может быть несколько локалей. Испанский - Мексика и Испания и т.д.

*Вопрос 1*: Какие выгоды от использования `PyICU`  и какие "проблемы" возможны при "ручной" подмене сокращений месяцев.  По названию файла я могу понять - какой там язык.

*Вопрос 2*:  Может появился какой-то новый модуль, который парсит дату без необхожимости подсказывать ему язык?

*Вопрос 3, короткий)*: Как парсить дату при чтении из `csv` если там разные языки в дате?

**Добавлено.** Думаю, меня устроит решение, приведенное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061724/panda-to-datetime-raises-warning-tzname-cet-identified-but-not-understood) а таблицу всех зон с часами смещения можно взять [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206500/how-to-convert-a-string-datetime-with-unknown-timezone-to-timestamp-in-python).

Comment: А в какой-то другой колонке там нет информации, на каком языке дата? Всё-таки думаю не всегда по написанию месяцев можно правильно отличить один язык от другого, наверняка есть пересечения.

Comment: @CrazyElf   один файл - один язык. Только  pd.to_datetime()  понимает только английский.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решился-таки в отдельном окружении установить подходящий мне `PyICU-2.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` взятый [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu).  Позаимствов код из приведенных источников и плюнув на зональное время, получил универсальный парсер:

```
import icu  # PyICU  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu
# import pytz  # $ pip install pytz

def parse_date_tz(date_str: str, locale: str) -> datetime:
    """
    Parse datetime string with locale shortcut specified to naive datetime.

    Parameters
    ----------
    date_str : str
        datetime stamp to be parsed.
        Example: "1 ago 2021 00:31:47 GMT-7"
    locale : str
        Standart locale shortcut.
        Example: 'es_MX'

    Returns
    -------
    datetime.datetime
        parsed naive datetime.


    >>> parse_date_tz("1 ago 2021 00:31:47 GMT-7", 'es_MX')
    >>> datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 31, 47)

    """
    tz = icu.ICUtzinfo.getDefault()  # any ICU timezone will do here
    df = icu.DateFormat.createDateTimeInstance(icu.DateFormat.MEDIUM,
                                               icu.DateFormat.MEDIUM,
                                               icu.Locale(locale))
    df.setTimeZone(tz.timezone)
    ts = df.parse(date_str)  # u'3 févr. 2015 14:26:00 CET'  NOTE: CET is ignored
    naive_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz).replace(tzinfo=None)
    return naive_dt
```

Ну и применяется он прекрасно к нужному столбцу строк примерно так:

```
df_df.loc[:, "fecha/hora"] = df_df["fecha/hora"].apply(parse_date_tz, locale='es_MX')
```

Поскольку имя файла содержит аббревиатуру страны, локаль найти не сложно. Скажем  'es_MX' или 'es_ES'.
Работает. Будут проблемы - подправлю ответ. )

**Добавлено 2022.08.06**
Пока все работает.
Единственное [уточнение](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/stable/user-guide/wheel-files.html). В `conda` лучше устанавливать, используя параметр `--no-deps`.